# os.system taskkill in for-loop

Tags: python, windows, loops

I have a script that opens a specified URL in chrome, shows it for 10 seconds before closing Chrome and then waits another 10 seconds before opening the same URL again (some memory training for the persons I want to use it for).

Now the problem is that Chrome closes the first time, but then the second time in the loop it doesn't close at all. No errors or warnings. I need this loop to run three times.

Am I missing something here?

```
import webbrowser
import os
import time

url = '<url>'
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'

for i in range(3):
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open_new(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system("taskkill /f /t /im chrome.exe")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Put `print(f"Run {i}", flush=True)` after the `open_new` call. Does the script reach it on the second loop? My guess would be the second launch is, for whatever reason, launching in a synchronous fashion (so `open_new` doesn't return until the browser is closed, and you never reach the `sleep` or the `taskkill`). Would also be useful to separate `get` from `open_new`, and `print(type(result_of_get))` to confirm if it thinks it's using the backgrounded class or not.

Comment: With the script you see in my question, Run 1 is never reached indeed. I separated `get` and `open_new` like you suggested and now it works. The problem is that I want to open an incognito chrome session, which is done the first time but not the second time. The second time it's a 'normal' Chrome session. I use this to open the incognito chrome session: `C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s --incognito`. Any idea why that is happening?